# Thermal velocity/agitation--why don't we feel 'hit' by ambient gases?

Tags: thermodynamics, forces, velocity, molecules, gas

If I'm not mistaken, the molecules in gas move at insane speeds at room temperature (for some gases, ~1 km/s) due to thermal agitation. Why don't we feel 'hit' by this random motion?

https://www.pfeiffer-vacuum.com/en/know-how/introduction-to-vacuum-technology/fundamentals/thermal-velocity/
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_theory_of_gases

Comment: We do feel it. It's called "air pressure". But since we have evolved to live in conditions where it occurs all the time, it causes us no harm and our nervous system and brain simply ignores it. In fact would be a huge force (about 1 tonne per square foot!) if it was not "balanced" by the fact that it is applied to "both sides" of everything, so the *resultant* force is zero..

Comment: Re, "...air pressure...," It would feel a bit different if you were shrunk down to the size of a grain of pollen:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_motion